# How do you calculate the expectation without a pdf in the context of Center limit theorem, variance

Tags: variance, mean, expected-value, density-function

Given Problem 1)
[image: problem]

To get the variance and covariance the following steps are taken:
[image: variance steps]

In the step below to calculate E[Z^2] how do we approach this without a known pdf? For completeness would finding E[cos(theta)^2] be the same set of steps? But this is different because at least we know that theta has a uniform distribution?
[image: confusion]

Maybe what I'm looking for is a trick, theorem or a property? I'm not completely sure how to fill my misunderstanding in this single step. Otherwise everything else in the problem makes complete sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E[Z^2] = Var(Z) + E[Z]^2 = \sigma^2 + \mu^2$

The mean and variance of Z is given in the question.